# PHP Ajax callback specified data from my php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

OK , here is my issue;

My issue is that when i callback my php file with ajax it calls all the content of my file

here is my code

my source.php file which including my view.php file

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
       echo "OK";
    }
  include_once "view.php";
?>
```

my view.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>


<h1>Form</h1>

<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" /><br>
    <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#sub").click(function(){


        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: $('#form').serialize(),
           success: function(slider_data){
             $("#result").text(slider_data);
           }
        });

          return false;
       });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Now when i submit my form 
my  #result here is

```
OK<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Hello!</title>
 </head>

 <body>


 <h1>Form</h1>

 <form action="" method="post" id="form">
 <input type="text" name="test" id="test" /><br>
 <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" />
 </form>

 <div id="result"></div>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#sub").click(function(){


 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 data: $('#form').serialize(),
 success: function(slider_data){
 $("#result").text(slider_data);
 }
 });

 return false;
 });
 });
 </script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

i want to show only the word "OK" or whatever i want and prevet sending all data and included file

Comment: because you have `include` in `source.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have `include` in `source.php` that's why you are getting `view.php` again.

change your code like this

source.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
       echo "OK";
    }
?>
```

`<script>` in view.php will be like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#sub").click(function(event){
        event.prevantDefault();

        $.ajax({
           url:"source.php" // url to source.php 
           type: "POST",
           data: $('#form').serialize(),
           success: function(slider_data){
             $("#result").text(slider_data);
           }
        });

          return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but as i said in previous comment i want to remove that refresh confirm :)

Comment: try removing `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: if i removed it , it will show me again my view file data :)

Comment: have you removed `include` from source.php, and added `url:` in your `$.ajax` ?

Comment: But why i remove my included file !! i want to display my view file in my source file and wantr the default url to be the same page (source.php) without writing it ^_^

Comment: it's working from my side, with only adding `die();` after echo.

Comment: What if i have more than one field ?

Comment: you can take one hidden field and then check it with `isset()` and it's `value` then inside that `IF` do stuff.

Comment: Thanks buddy that works , but still have one last issue 

when i try to echo for example echo $_POST['test']."<br>"; the output is for example test<br>
i want to read it as an html tag not as a string

Comment: change `.text()` to `.html()` like this `$("#result").html(slider_data);`

Comment: Yes , thanks buddy , but there is something i forgot ,
what if i have header file that i include in my source then my form code operations then including view file 
how to prevent the header file to be included too ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `e.prevantDefault();` in order to prevent form submission. And also add a `die()` after your `echo 'Ok';` to stop the execution .So try like this

```
 $("#sub").click(function(e){
        e.prevantDefault();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: $('#form').serialize(),
           success: function(slider_data){
             $("#result").text(slider_data);
           }
        });
  });

if(isset($_POST['test'])){
   echo "OK";
   die();
}
include_once "view.php";
```

Comment: Thanks , works perfectly but still there an issue, now when i submit my form , when i refresh the page it shows me that alert message to refresh the page or not which i disabled it in my previous code with return false , but when i added it to your code ,it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the page was requested with AJAX, and only include the view if it's not.

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
   echo "OK";
}

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
    include_once 'view.php'; 
}
```

The second `if` checks if the page was *not* requested with AJAX.

Echoing "ok" before the `include_once` would break the site, since it outputs content before the `<DOCTYPE html>` tag.