# PHP Ajax return specified data from my php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

OK i asked this question about some hours ago but i face a new problem with my code

firstly here is my previous issue

[PHP Ajax callback specified data from my php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967972/php-ajax-callback-specified-data-from-my-php/23968005?noredirect=1#comment36927775_23968005)

My problem now is when my source.php file have some files to be included

for example

```
include_once "header.php";
include_once "view.php"; // where my form is 
include_once "footer.php";
```

when i submit my form it returns all data from my source.php file as i didn't asign any url values

i can prevent including footer.php file by adding exit or die function so it won't be loaded again

but the problem here is in my header.php

how to prevent from including all data in my source.php file and return just the data

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` statement:

```
if (whatever) {
    include_once("header.php");
}
include_once("view.php");
if (whatever) {
    include_once("footer.php");
}
```

Comment: why shoud i use if for including my header,footer !!

It doesn't make any sense for doing this 

i just want to return specified data from my source.php file :)

Comment: Why do you have a header and footer in this file in the first place?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use different scripts for displaying web pages and for responding to AJAX calls. Then you don't have to worry about stuff like this.

Comment: i want to have all my page included in my index page 

,so i'm including my header , then my content page => view.php file and finally my footer page

Comment: OK, then that's why you have to do this. When it's being used to respond to an AJAX call, you don't want to send the header and footer, so you skip over them with `if`.